# Mapbox: Refreshing an annotationView when the annotation changes

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I have custom annotations that sometimes display a textView above them.
They don't display a textView if a variable named text on my annotation is nil.

An annotation may have text to display, but the value of the text variable could change while the annotation is being displayed. In this case I would like the annotation to refresh so that it is no longer displaying the textView.

I already have a delegate function that either creates an annotation with a textView if the annotations text variable is set and creates an annotation without a textView if the text variable of the annotation is not set, it works something like this, although this is not the actual code

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView?{
    if annotation is MyCustomAnnotation{
        if annotation.hasText(){
            return MyCustomAnnotationView(hasText: True)
        }else{
            return ViewWithoutTextView(hasText: False)
        }
    }
```

But if the annotation changes from having text to not having text or vice versa while the annotation is already being displayed, then I don't know how to refresh this or call this again so that the right annotation view is displayed

Comment: Once the annotation is displayed, you cannot simply update it. You need to delete it and then add it back onto the mapView with its new/updated state.

Comment: @Magnas I was thinking of adding a reference to the view on my annotation, then having didSets that update my view when the variables on the annotations change. What's your opinion? Would this be more efficient? Is it bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

As @Magnas said in the comment, you would have to remove the annotation and re-add it to update the state.

It would be better to create one custom annotation view that has the logic to handle hiding/showing of the text view inside it. Then you just hold onto a reference of the annotation and update that through the `annotationView` without going through and messing with map annotations at all.

A rough example (lots of blanks to fill):

```
// your methods in your custom annotation. Use these wherever you want to change things
class CustomAnnotation: MGLAnnotationView {
  func showText() { }
  func hideText() { }
}

// Define data structure to access your annotation with some kind of key
dataSourceToAnnotationView: [String: CustomAnnotation]


// save your annotations so you can access them later
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {        
  var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "customReuseId")
  if annotationView == nil {
    annotationView = CustomAnnotation()
    let key = "exampleKeyString"
    dataSourceToAnnotationView[key] = annotationView as! CustomAnnotation
  }
    
  return annotationView
}
```